# PHP form not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: php, html, internet-explorer, contacts

I created this contact form, it works perfectly in firefox and chrome but in internet explorer it wont allow you to input text (clicking on the form fields does nothing) the submit button works but only sends a blank message because no text can be entered. Also when you press submit it tries to open mail.php in a firefox page, i am only testing locally on my pc could this be the issue?

PHP is this :

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $formcontent="This message has been generated from the Contact page \n Name: $name \n Phone: $phone \n Email: $email \n Message: $message";
    $recipient = "myemail@myemail.co.uk";
    $subject = "Enquiry From contact page";
    $mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
    mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
    header('Location: ../contact2.html');
?>
```

HTML is:

```
<form id="form1" action="PHP/mail.php" method="post">
    <label>Name <span class="small">Add your name</span></label> 
    <input type="text" name="name"><br>
    <label>Email <span class="small">Enter a Valid Email</span></label> 
    <input type="text" name="email"><br>
    <label>Phone <span class="small">Add a Phone Number</span></label> 
    <input type="text" name="phone"><br>

    <br>
    <br>

    <label>Message <span class="small">Type Your Message</span></label> 
    <textarea name="message" rows="6" cols="25">
    </textarea><br>
    <button type="submit" value="Send" style="margin-top:15px;">Submit</button>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: there are some javascript related with it i suppose?

Comment: You need to provide more info, namely: any JS that could disable the elements. On a tangent, though, you really should /> those inputs.

Comment: did you try to do the `<input type="submit" value="Send">` ? There is some bugs on IE with button element

Comment: perhaps some div is overlapping the text area in IE ?

Comment: there is not such thing like "PHP form".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on purely on the form you have I was able to enter text in the form in Chrome, FireFox and IE8.

Take your html form code and place it in an independent file HTML file and test in IE to see if you get the same behavior.

Testing an HTML file will narrow the problem down to just checking the browser removing other variables like your PHP server or javascript.

-*If you get the same issue:* it is a IE issue independent to that PC.

-*If you do not get the same issue:* it may be a problem with your php configuration or javascript.

```
            <form id="form1" action="PHP/mail.php" method="post">
                <label>Name <span class="small">Add your name</span></label> <input type="text" name="name" /><br />
                <label>Email <span class="small">Enter a Valid Email</span></label> <input type="text" name="email" /><br />
                <label>Phone <span class="small">Add a Phone Number</span></label> <input type="text" name="phone" /><br />
                <br>
                <br>
                <label>Message <span class="small">Type Your Message</span></label> 
                <textarea name="message" rows="6" cols="25">
                </textarea><br>
                <button type="submit" value="Send" style="margin-top:15px;">Submit</button>
                <div class="spacer"></div>
            </form>
```

Comment: Thanks Mike, i tried what you said and it does allow text input now since i changed button to input type=submit, but when clicking submit in IE it is still producing the same result so its a PC issue my end?

Comment: An easy way to check without standing up another server or dev environment is to take the html file to another device that is running IE you may have.  But I was able to have everything work for your form  on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

You should be closing your  tags, like so:

```
<input type="text" name="email" />
```

The same goes for your newline tags:

```
<br />
```

Any tag that doesn't require content in the middle should be closed like that. The image tag would be another example.

```
<img src="myimg.png" />
```

Also, I would use an  button because I think it makes the code look cleaner:

```
<input type="submit" value="Send" />
```

Comment: Ok i have closed all my tags correctly now and have replaced <button> with the <input type="submit" value="send /> it is now letting me enter text but on clicking submit it attempts to open mail.php in a new firefox tab and does nothing, There is no javascript on this page just html linking to the php file and CSS.

Comment: That should be a fairly simple fix. Try adding a target to your form tag, like this:

    <form id="form1" action="PHP/mail.php" method="post" target="_self"> If you continue to have problems I can help you work this out, just contact me through the "Contact" tab at http://gatorfunk.com - I will email you back with a response.