# Emailing file using PHP not working in IE 8

Tags: php, html, forms, internet-explorer

I have a form that allows you to input data and attach a file and email it. It works on my phone, on safari, firefox, and chrome, but I cannot get it to work in IE. (It wont even post to the php page.)

HTML:

```
<form method="post" id="mainForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="email.php">
        <span class="hide" id="status"></span>
        <div class="rowElem">
            <label for="name">Member Name:</label>
            <div class="formRight">
                <input id="name" type="text" name="name" required placeholder="John Doe" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rowElem">
            <label for="email">Member Email: </label>
            <div class="formRight">
                <input id="email" type="email" name="email"  required placeholder="john.doe@email.com" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rowElem">
            <label for="subject">Subject: </label>
            <div class="formRight">
                <input id="subject" type="text" name="subject"  required placeholder="Phone Call Follow Up"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rowElem">
            <label for="message">Message: </label>
            <div class="formRight">
                <textarea id="message" name="message"  required ></textarea> 
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rowElem">
            <label for="attachment">Attachment: </label>
            <div class="formRight">
                <input id="attachment" type="file" name="attachment"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rowElem">
            <button class="submit">Send Email</button>
            <button class="reset" onClick="resetForm()">Reset Form</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php 
    $membername = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $content = $_POST['message'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];

    $maxTotalAttachments=5097152; //Maximum of 2 MB total attachments, in bytes
    $boundary_text = uniqid();
    $boundary = "--".$boundary_text."\r\n";
    $boundary_last = "--".$boundary_text."--\r\n";

     //Build up the list of attachments, 
    //getting a total size and adding boundaries as needed
     $emailAttachments = "";
     $totalAttachmentSize = 0;
     foreach ($_FILES as $file) {
        //In case some file inputs are left blank - ignore them
        if ($file['error'] == 0 && $file['size'] > 0){
             $fileContents = file_get_contents($file['tmp_name']);
             $totalAttachmentSize += $file['size']; //size in bytes
             $emailAttachments .= "Content-Type: " 
            .$file['type'] . "; name=\"" . basename($file['name']) . "\"\r\n"
            ."Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n"
            ."Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" 
            .basename($file['name']) . "\"\r\n"
            ."\r\n"
            //Convert the file's binary info into ASCII characters
            .chunk_split(base64_encode($fileContents))
             .$boundary;
         }
    }
  //Now all the attachment data is ready to insert into the email body.
  //If the file was too big for PHP, it may show as having 0 size
  if ($totalAttachmentSize == 0) {
    echo "Message not sent. Either no file was attached, or it was bigger than PHP is configured to accept.  ".basename($file['name']);
}
  //Now make sure it doesn't exceed this function's specified limit:
  else if ($totalAttachmentSize>$maxTotalAttachments) {
    echo "Message not sent. Total attachments can't exceed " .  $maxTotalAttachments . " bytes.";
  }
  //Everything is OK - let's build up the email
  else {  
    $to = $email;
    $subject = $subject;
    $from = "do-not-reply@someemail.com";
    $headers = "From: ".$from." \r\n";
    $headers .= 'Bcc: someone@someemail.com' . "\r\n";
    $headers .=     "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"
    ."Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary_text\"" . "\r\n";  
    $message .="If you can see this, your email client "
    ."doesn't accept MIME types!\r\n"
    .$boundary;

    $message .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\r\n"
    ."Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n" 
    //Inert the HTML message body you passed into this function
    ."Hello ".$membername."<br><br>" . $content . "<br><br> Please do not reply to this message. Replies to this message are routed to an unmonitored mailbox. If you have questions please go to... You may also call us at .... Thank you. " . "\r\n";

    //Insert the attachment information we built up above.
    //Each of those attachments ends in a regular boundary string   

    $message .= $emailAttachments

    //This section ends in a terminating boundary string - meaning
    //"that was the last section, we're done"
    .$boundary_last;

    if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)){
     echo 'some html goes here.';  
    } 
    else {
      echo 'Error - mail not sent.';
    }
  }    

?>
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" is never a good problem description. What happens? What error messages do you get?

Comment: Try changing the submit `<button>` to an `<input type="submit"...` and see if that works...

Comment: email function doesn't matter which browser are you using IMO. I am assuming there could be a minor syntax problem here.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Doesn't work is as specific as it gets. No error, it just does not do anything at all.

Comment: @Jack Did you check your php error_log?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not the PHP as it works in everything else, but what is wrong with the syntax? I use `<button>` for several forms, so I doubt that's the issue.

Comment: @DrixsonOseña it's not submitting at all, so the call to the PHP script is not being made.

Comment: @Jack Give it a try and see (input instead of button). Also check if you have `<!DOCTYPE html>` instead of just `<html>`. I know that early versions of IE buck real hard when special documents as such doesn't have that document declaration. Hey, it's worth a shot. And, I would suggest you find a few other file attachment functions instead of trying to patch this one up.

Comment: @Jack I also noticed a missing semi-colon in `$message .= $emailAttachments` try adding one at the end like this `$message .= $emailAttachments;` see if that gets it going. That alone will break your code.

Comment: That's not missing :D there is a few carriage returns between it and the next line, but if there were not any, it would read: `$message .= $emailAttachments .$boundary_last;` Good catch though.

Comment: @Jack I recommend not breaking those up. IE might be bucking just because of that. All the more reasons I don't use IE.

Comment: Does your HTML [validate](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input)? If you are correct in that the form is not even posting, the problem is likely with the html and not the php. I mention the `button` vs `input` test because I've seen ie8 do funny things with `buttons` when in 'compatibility mode`. It's worth a try.

Comment: @Fred-ii- the doctype is set. And I guess finding another way may have to be the solution.

Comment: @Fred-ii why would IE buck because of line breaks in the PHP code?

Comment: @Carl it validates fine aside from a warning on the label.

Comment: @Jack I tested your code and it's not "attaching" a file to the message, it's "embedding" it. Your headers need to be reworked, so I recommend finding a file attachment function that works. I could fix it, but that could take 1/2 hour. The time I spend on fixing it, would be better spent if you found another function that's been `tried-tested-true`. Best I can tell you, and you now know what is actually wrong with it. It's "embedding", not attaching.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Um, what does that have to do with the form not submitting from IE? I get you see something in the PHP that you would do a different way, and you may have a point, but the form does not even submit in IE.

Comment: @Jack That I couldn't say. I can say this though, your headers are getting mixed into the `message` part of it, probably why IE's bucking. I retested and got back the same results, right after where it says `"You may also call us at .... Thank you."` in your code, is where the problem starts.

Comment: @Jack This line should be part of your headers and not `message` --- `$message .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\r\n"`

Comment: @Fred-ii- That's a good catch, I'll fix it, but that still doesn't explain why the form does not submit. You're trying to fix issues that I'm not getting errors from. If there was a problem with `sendmail` working it would return  `else {
      echo 'Error - mail not sent.';
    }`Which it does not. That being said, you've helped me clean up the php, but have not helped me get anywhere with the issue I asked about.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37561/discussion-between-jack-and-fred-ii)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE is not executing the form because of the use of `<button>` without `type="submit"` as a means to submit, such as the one you presently have in your form:

```
<button class="submit">Send Email</button>
```

You can use an input type like this:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Email">
```

or add `type="submit"` to your present button such as:

```
<button class="submit" type="submit">Send Email</button>
```

I tested it and IE and it did not want to send the form as a "button" without `type="submit"` included.

Another problem was with the handler. Header information was being leaked into the message body area itself, so I used one of my attachment handlers in my answer below.

**For example, here is a partial copy of the message body with the leakage:**

> Hello Fred
>
> Testing message
>
> Please do not reply to this message. Replies to this message are routed to an unmonitored mailbox. If you have questions please go to... You may also call us at .... Thank you. Content-Type: image/jpeg; name="test_image.jpg" Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 Content-disposition: attachment; filename="test_image.jpg" LzlqLzRBQVFTa1pKUmdBQkFnQUFaQUJrQUFELzdBQVJSSFZqYTNrQUFRQUVB.............................

Using the following form and handler, was able to successfully send an Email with an attachment with both IE 7 and FF 24.

### HTML form

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="sendmail_attach.php" method="post" name="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table width="343" border="1">

<tr>
<td>Name</td>
<td><input name="txtFormName" type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<td>Form Email</td>
<td><input name="txtFormEmail" type="text"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Message:</td>
<td><textarea name="txtDescription" cols="30" rows="4" id="txtDescription"></textarea></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Attachment</td>
<td><input name="fileAttach" type="file"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Message"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

### PHP hander (sendmail_attach.php)

```
<?php
$strTo = "email@example.com";
$strSubject = "Email attach subject";
$strMessage = nl2br($_POST["txtDescription"]);

//*** Uniqid Session ***//
$strSid = md5(uniqid(time()));

$strHeader = "";
$strHeader .= "From: ".$_POST["txtFormName"]."<".$_POST["txtFormEmail"].">\nReply-To: ".$_POST["txtFormEmail"]."";

$strHeader .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$strHeader .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$strSid."\"\n\n";
$strHeader .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n";

$strHeader .= "--".$strSid."\n";
$strHeader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n";
$strHeader .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n";
$strHeader .= $strMessage."\n\n";

//*** Attachment ***//
if($_FILES["fileAttach"]["name"] != "")
{
$strFilesName = $_FILES["fileAttach"]["name"];
$strContent = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES["fileAttach"]["tmp_name"])));
$strHeader .= "--".$strSid."\n";
$strHeader .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$strFilesName."\"\n";
$strHeader .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n";
$strHeader .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$strFilesName."\"\n\n";
$strHeader .= $strContent."\n\n";
}

$flgSend = @mail($strTo,$strSubject,null,$strHeader);  // @ = No Show Error //

if($flgSend)
{
echo "Mail send completed.";
}
else
{
echo "Cannot send mail.";
}
?>
```

Comment: `<button type="submit">` should work just as well as `<input type="submit">`

Comment: @Phil Strangely enough, not in my IE 7 Phil, only an input type. I fully test everything. And I suspect that is what's going on with the OP also.

Comment: @Phil Later versions of IE may very well support `<button>`, yet I suspect that both the OP's version being `8` and mine is `7`, may very well react the same way.

Comment: @Phil After closer inspection of the OP's original code, he did not have `type="submit"` for his Submit button being `<button class="submit">Send Email</button>` - However I did test again in IE7 using `<button class="submit" type="submit">Send Email</button>` and that did in fact submit the form. You were indeed correct about what you said. I forgot to mention the fact about the OP's button in his question.

Comment: @Fred-ii- the lack of `type` on the `button` was the issue. Thanks.

Comment: @Jack You're welcome Jack. If you wish to close this question as being answered and no longer remain as being "unanswered, to accept my answer, thank you. Cheers, glad I could help.

Comment: @Fred-ii- fyi, I marked it as correct, but I ended up not needing anything else in your post.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the answer on this Stack Overflow question:
[PHP form not working in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13493565/php-form-not-working-in-internet-explorer)

It may be something in the form structure.

Comment: Appreciate the answer, but it worked before I added the File Attachment.